# Can't run callback function after returning promise using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, javascript-objects, es6-promise, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `google charts` to create line charts. and then passing the html generated to `wkhtmltopdf` **version** 0.12.5 (with patched qt) in windows, which is a shell utility to convert html pages to PDF.

wkhtmltopdf uses old version of `webkit` (browser engine) to execute javascript code so it considers `Promise` as a plain `object` in addition to **not** supporting other ES6 features.

Now coming to question.

**The JS code[main.js]:**

```
1. google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

2. google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
3.  drawChart();
4. });

5. function drawChart() {
6. var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
7.  [
8.  // some data
9.  ]
10.  );
11. var options = {
12    // some options
13. };

14. var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
15.    document.getElementById("node_chart_div1") // a div element in html
16.  );

17.  chart.draw(data, options);
18. }
```

**HTML code:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Line Chart</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
      integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="node_chart_div1" class="cellchart"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Running the above code displays the chart in the browser.

But running it through `wkhtmltopdf` gives a blank PDF.

upon inspecting i found that `google.setOnLoadCallback()` at line number 2 in `main.js` returns a `Promise` object, which is well interpreted by the browser engine.

But running it through a `wkhtmltopdf` treats it as a plain `object` and does not execute any code written inside its callback (which in this case is `drawChart` function).

My query is:

- Is there any js wrapper code to convert the object returned in `wkhtmltopdf` to standard JS `Promise` object.

  OR
- Is there any total different approach/workaround to fix it.

**command used for converting html page to PDF**

```
wkhtmltopdf https://www.example.com/index.html output.pdf
```

find live demo of above code at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qcbk65t9/) link.

Any help/suggestion is well appreciated.